# creating a vertical line (HTML) in an email signature for outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, signature

Looking for a solution to a problem that I have been dealing with while formatting an HTML e-mail signature for Outlook. At this time, I am looking for a way to insert a vertical line between two tables that are nested within each other. (Imaged below)

I am avoiding using the "border" option as I am looking to adjust the height of the vertical line as well. I have attached below an image of the signature, as well as some of the code that may help give more of an insight into what I am looking for.

**note: have also attempted to use the <*hr> tag with styling/nested ANOTHER table within the <*td> tags/used an <*img> of the vertical line

```
</table> -- end of 1st nested table
      <span class="phone" style="color:black;font-family: Corbel; font-size:14.5px; text-align: left;">
        %%PhoneNumber%%
      </span>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
       --- this is where I have been placing the line
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="50%" border-collapse="collapse" style="display: flex; padding-left: 20px;"> -- beginning of second nested table
        <tbody>
          <tr>
```

desired outcome is yellow line in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOjjD.png

Comment: What if you create a div with height: 100%, width: 2px, and background: black?

Comment: @GonePhishing my apologies for not mentioning-- I have attempted to use divs (spans too not sure if that was best practices) but Outlook ignores a lot of the inline-styling that is applied. just tried it again tho and still no luck

Comment: the little code you have posted are a mess, no opening td's tags and missing tr's... if that's your real code it's logical nothing works, specially taking into account you want to use html 1.0 which do not allow any single mistake. However, if you have a well structured html, the idea is right. in that row you should have 3 cells, all 3 of them with fixed width (which should the sum of all 3 should match  the width of the parent) and the center cell width should just have inline styles with a width of whatever pixels width you want the line plus background-color... no need for anything inside.